# mtscra (library for reading card on swipe the card)library callbacks not calling

Tags: android

i am using this library (mtscra) for Magtech Dynamag Card reader . the library provides many callbacks but the problem is that only one callback is called which is
onDeviceStateChange().  but the other callbacks is not calling although data is reading successfully from the reader.

```
  private class SCRAHandlerCallback implements Handler.Callback {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MTSCRAEvent.OnDeviceConnectionStateChanged:
                OnDeviceStateChanged((MTConnectionState) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTSCRAEvent.OnCardDataStateChanged:
                OnCardDataStateChanged((MTCardDataState) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTSCRAEvent.OnDataReceived:
                OnCardDataReceived((IMTCardData) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTSCRAEvent.OnDeviceResponse:
                //   OnDeviceResponse((String) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTEMVEvent.OnTransactionStatus:
                //    OnTransactionStatus((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTEMVEvent.OnDisplayMessageRequest:
                //   OnDisplayMessageRequest((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTEMVEvent.OnUserSelectionRequest:
                //     OnUserSelectionRequest((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTEMVEvent.OnARQCReceived:
                //   OnARQCReceived((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MTEMVEvent.OnTransactionResult:
                //   OnTransactionResult((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;

            case MTEMVEvent.OnEMVCommandResult:
                //    OnEMVCommandResult((byte[]) msg.obj);
                break;

            case MTEMVEvent.OnDeviceExtendedResponse:
                //   OnDeviceExtendedResponse((String) msg.obj);
                break;
        }
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution after long time , the main problem was my card reader device did not match with the library i use and i am 
 able to get track to data from serial ports of android device

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly? Did you have to use a different library? It's my understanding that MTSCRA is the correct library to use on Android with the Dynamag reader - I'm running into the same issue as you however, where my callbacks aren't being triggered